# Katalon : Unable to click on object after use switchTo and waitForElementClickable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I have problem with find element in my script. I use switchToframe and waitForElementClickable and a still have error

```
Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/1_2.Wniosek_o_OsFiz_v2/Page_Do wysyki i robocze - seap-testskgpl/label_Zaznacz lini' (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/1_2.Wniosek_o_OsFiz_v2/Page_Do wysyki i robocze - seap-testskgpl/label_Zaznacz lini'
at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.click(ClickKeyword.groovy:76)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.execute(ClickKeyword.groovy:43)
at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:72)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.click(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:616)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$click$1.call(Unknown Source)
at 1_2.Wniosek_o_OsFiz_v2.run(1_2.Wniosek_o_OsFiz_v2:85)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
at TempTestCase1586510087999.run(TempTestCase1586510087999.groovy:23)
```

This is details for my element:
[image]

And this is my code (I still work in iframe, page reload. Element is in this same iframe):

```
WebUI.waitForElementClickable(findTestObject('Object Repository/1_2.Wniosek_o_OsFiz_v2/Page_Do wysyki i robocze - seap-testskgpl/label_Zaznacz lini'), 
10)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/1_2.Wniosek_o_OsFiz_v2/Page_Do wysyki i robocze - seap-testskgpl/label_Zaznacz lini'))
```

[image]

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: To what element is the xpath `//div[@id='document0']/div[3]/label` refering to? The iframe object or the link you are trying to click? Did you use the web-recorder to get the element xpath?

Comment: Yes I use web-recorder.

Comment: I don't know which element this xpath refers to. I search in source and I don`t find.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath for the link you are trying to get is generated by web-recorder. Those selectors tend to be flaky because they are dynamic (so, they won't be the same every time you run the tests). I suggest you learn how to get the XPath yourself using Google DevTools or similar.

In this particular case, change the value of **Selected Locator** from `//div[@id='document0']/div[3]/label` to `//a[@title='Documenty do wysylki']`.

Comment: switch to default content is used after you are done with iframe.

Comment: Mrse have you maybe any idea?